# How would one go about writing functions for repetitive tasks in Sublime Text?

Tags: sublimetext2

In Vim, my editor of choice (A clear case of Stockholm syndrome, if ever there was one) I find myself often writing small functions that contain, in a lot of cases, a series of regex expressions.

Couldn't be simpler really, write a function, source it, re-use for as long as needed, and if it's gonna be needed in a future save to some file.

How would one go about writing such functions in Sublime Text editor? For example, how could one write a function (or something) that would do two regex replacements in a file? All examples welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to go about this would be through [snippets](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html) (also check out the [reference here](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/snippets.html)). You can do everything from a simple insertion of text to complex Perl style regexes. For examples, search through the `Packages/` subdirectories for `.sublime-snippet` files.

Once written, the snippets can then be executed either through the built-in `<tabTrigger>` command (type that text, then hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> to run it) or by setting a particular key combination. Under `Preferences -> Key Bindings - User`, add a new key combo like so:

```json
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+alt+shift+r"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": { "name": "Packages/User/replace_stuff.sublime-snippet" } }
]
```

Good luck!